# Send this page to e-reader services

Tags: kindle

This question should maybe be on Webmaster Stackexchange, but that site does not have any applicable tags.

Is there a consistent way of "sending" a document to the user's e-reading device (regardless of which popular platform/service they use) in the same way that Amazon's Kindle retrieves documents sent to the user's "kindle email address"?

Achieving this as I envision would have a user of my site 1. click "send to my reading device" 2. enter their login credentials for their reading device 3. the document is sent and immediately available on the device (or application -- native, web, or phone).

Assume that I can provide whatever file format is needed, as long as it can represent basic rich text on the device.

Comment: I'd love to see such a feature implemented on all e-reading devises. Unfortunately Kindle seems to be the only one of a kind. And Amazon seems to be the smartest player on this market.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2012 there is no way to send content directly to a user's Kindle.

The Kindle downloads content only from Amazon or that was sideloaded via USB.  To get content from Amazon the user must either 'purchase' it from the Amazon store or send it their Personal Document email address, which then creates a verified Amazon item just for that user.